# prove $m^{m-1} < (m-1)^m$ for m > 3

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I found that if m > 3 then $m^{m-1} < (m-1)^m$ for m > 3 seems to hold true for a lot of cases. Can someone prove this inductively ?

Comment: set $m=x$ and $4m-1=y$ then we get $x^y<y^x$ which is true for $x>y$ and $x>3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When $m=4$, then $(m-1)^m=3^4>4^3=m^{m-1}$, so the inequality holds for $m=4$.

2) Assume that $(m-1)^m>m^{m-1}$ for some integer $m\ge4$.

Then $\displaystyle m^{m+1}=\frac{m^{m+1}}{(m-1)^m}\cdot(m-1)^m>\frac{m^{m+1}}{(m-1)^m}\cdot m^{m-1}=\frac{(m^2)^m}{(m-1)^m}>\frac{(m^2-1)^m}{(m-1)^m}$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle=\frac{(m-1)^{m}(m+1)^m}{(m-1)^m}=(m+1)^m$, so the assertion holds for $m+1$.

Therefore $(m-1)^m>m^{m-1}$ for all integers $m\ge4$.

Comment: shouldn't the first inequality for $m^{m+1}$ be $m^{m+1} > $(m+1)$^{m+1}$ ?

Comment: That doesn't seem right, since $m+1>m$, but let me know if you think something in this argument is mistaken.

Comment: sorry i meant $m^{m+1} > (m+1)^{m}$

Comment: That is what I am trying to prove in step 2, if I did it  correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Take logarithms. We just have to prove that
$$ f(n)=\frac{n}{\log n} $$
is an increasing function for $n\geq 3$, or that
$$ g(n) = \frac{\log n}{n} $$
is a decreasing function on the same set.

This is a one-shot-one-kill problem through derivatives, since:
$$ g'(x)=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2} $$
gives that $g$ is a decreasing function on the set $x>e$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $f\colon x\in (1,\infty)\to x\ln(x-1) - (x-1)\ln x$ is strictly positive for $x > 2$. It is increasing, and cancels at $2$.